# Raise_exception not working with token base authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-testing

I'm trying to run my tests on status codes while i'm not providing token on POST request

So viewset looking like this:

```
class TopicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TopicSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly, )
    pagination_class = TopicPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Topic.objects.all().select_related(
            'owner',
        )
        return queryset
```

Permission class i'm using:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Test itself:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_topic_post_method_is_not_allowed_unauthenticated_user(api_client, topics_url):
    response = api_client.post(topics_url, data={'name': 'hello', 'slug': 'hello'})
    assert response.status_code == 401
```

So all i want is just a simple response like:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

But i'm getting html django generated page(screenshot from Postman):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set new permission classes via the class attribute, the the view will ignore the default list in the `settings.py` file.

You probably need to compose the permission list with the `IsAuthenticated`.
And the error you're getting is because of `request.user` is not returning a `CustomUser` instance, you may need to query that custom user if your auth system is not injecting its instance in your request.

You can try to change the permissions to:

```py
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
# or
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated & IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

Comment: Figured it out with copying has_permissions method from IsAuthententicated to my custom permissions class and moving if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS into it(has_permissions method). Thanks a lot.